# How to center two DIVS inside a parent DIV and ensure the image doesn't overlap the left DIV

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="serviceHolder brClear setCenter">
    <div style="float: left;  min-width: 30%; max-width: 40%; z-index: 100;">
        <div style="display: table; background: url('theImages/talentQuote.png') no-repeat center; background-size: 100% 100%; min-height: 160px; min-width: 160px; text-align: center;">
            <div style="color: #FFF; font-weight: bold; vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell; padding: 0 20px; font-family: 'trebuchet MS'"><xsl:value-of select="txtQuote" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; min-width: 60%; max-width: 50%; padding-top: 70px; text-align: left; z-index: 50;">
        <img src="{imgPicture/img/@src}" alt="{txtName}" />
    </d
```

iv>

Generates this on smaller screen (iphone 5s):

[image]

On desktop screen:

[image]

Really small screen:

[image]

How can I ensure

- The right DIV with the image has a `z-index` lower than the left DIV
  to ensure it is below the quote.
- The quote is resizing, how do I also ensure the image resizes and
  doesn't get cut off from the right as seen on the smaller screen.
- Center both inner DIV inside the parent DIV.

Comment: Can you please provide a JSFiddle and "name" your divs? Because inner DIV inside parent DIV is more Chinese than English when there are 4 nested divs...

Comment: `z-index` won't work unless the div's are positioned either `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`. `position:relative;` is proabbly what you are looking for.

Comment: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/djuv4kyr/1/

Comment: How is this question related to XSLT?

Comment: `<img src="{imgPicture/img/@src}" alt="{txtName}" />` and `<xsl:value-of select="txtQuote" />`

Comment: Still, I do not see how this is relevant to the question.

Comment: I removed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the right div with the image has a white background as well, remove the white background and save it as png.

To resize the img give it width in % as much as required (e.g. 60%) and just use width, do not use min-width and max-width to the parent div and the img should have a width 100%, display:block. In this way the img will resize and will not get cut.

Also add position relative to the quote div....this will help with indexing.

Regarding the centre of both the divs can you provide your code using jsfiddle...it will be easy to see, apart from that try using for both divs display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; remove float and for the parent div add margin:0 auto

Comment: I have bee able to make the changes, you can resize the screen and see that the img is resizing and not cutting.....both the divs are in the centre as well and I have set z-index as well. You would now have to make the actual changes to see the result

Comment: Do you have the Fiddle? ( it is `2` instead of `1` I got it ) When I resize it too small it cuts off, http://jsfiddle.net/djuv4kyr/2/

Comment: I made changes on the fiddle you gave me after that I updated it and when it is updated I believe the 1 changed to 2